# RabbitMQ: find reason for channel shutdown due to consumer exception

Tags: java, rabbitmq, amqp

I have an RPC server created with the RabbitMQ [Java client library](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client) and I get the following error when consuming a message:

```
com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: clean channel shutdown; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=200, reply-text=Closed due to exception from Consumer (amq.ctag-CAqHaJnRsaP6dfovPnR8lw) method handleDelivery for channel AMQChannel(amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672/,1), class-id=0, method-id=0)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:588)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.close(ChannelN.java:541)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.StrictExceptionHandler.handleChannelKiller(StrictExceptionHandler.java:72)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.StrictExceptionHandler.handleConsumerException(StrictExceptionHandler.java:61)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerDispatcher$5.run(ConsumerDispatcher.java:154)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ConsumerWorkService$WorkPoolRunnable.run(ConsumerWorkService.java:104)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

However, this only occurs if I make a certain change in the RPC client implementation, otherwise the RPC server works correctly. The message sent by the client is always the same, no matter whether the error occurs or not.

The RabbitMQ logs don't mention anything about the channel shutdown.

How can I find out in more detail what's the reason for the channel shutdown and consumer exception?

**EDIT**

Here is the code creating the connection, channel, and consumer. Nothing else uses this channel, and whenever a message is delivered from the `REQUEST_QUEUE` to this code, then the above error occurs.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
    factory.setHost("localhost");
    try {
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        channel = connection.createChannel();
        channel.queueDeclare(REQUEST_QUEUE, false, false, true, null);
        channel.basicConsume(REQUEST_QUEUE, true, RpcServer::onMsgReceived, RpcServer::onCancel);
        channel.addShutdownListener(new ShutdownListener() {
            @Override
            public void shutdownCompleted(ShutdownSignalException cause) {
                cause.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Waiting for RPC requests");
    } catch (IOException | TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you could provide details of what you were doing at the time the exception occurred. I agree the message in that log is not terribly helpful.

Comment: Could you indicate whether you have a channel dedicated to consumption, or if you use the **same** channel in different ways in the code?

Comment: I posted the code in the question. The channel is used only by this consumer. The code is very simple, and I have used it many times without problems. The problem occurs only in combination with this specific code that sends the message to the queue (RPC client).

Comment: Same thing is happening to me while using the last 4.x Java client. It seems to happen when I have multiple consumers running. Two will shut down and one will keep running without issue. If I run five consumer processes (not threads) two die pretty quickly and the others run for a while. I have never had all of them die. I traced the code in a debug session and it exits with an exception shutdown after the handle methods ends normally.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably happening because your connection is configured to use [com.rabbitmq.client.impl.StrictExceptionHandler](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/v5.7.3/src/main/java/com/rabbitmq/client/impl/StrictExceptionHandler.java#L24-L32) by default.

If you don't want the channel to be closed in case of exceptions, you might want to write your own exception handler, or maybe use [com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ForgivingExceptionHandler](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/v5.7.3/src/main/java/com/rabbitmq/client/impl/ForgivingExceptionHandler.java#L25-L33).

Notice also that by default the connection will use [com.rabbitmq.client.impl.DefaultExceptionHandler](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-java-client/blob/v5.7.3/src/main/java/com/rabbitmq/client/impl/DefaultExceptionHandler.java#L24), which extends **com.rabbitmq.client.impl.StrictExceptionHandler**.

One more thing. You can set the exception handler in the connection factory, using **setExceptionHandler** method.